# Time Series Cross Validation tsCV Method

Tags: r, time-series, cross-validation

I have a time-series that I am trying to fit an autoregression model to. I am trying to use the `tsCV` method. From the help page I find this:

> `tsCV` computes the forecast errors obtained by applying `forecastfunction` to subsets of the time series `y` using a rolling forecast origin.

and from the details section I see

> Let `y` contain the time series `y[1:T]`. Then `forecastfunction` is applied successively to the time series `y[1:t]`, for `t=1,…,T-h`, making predictions `f[t+h]`.

In the examples we have

```r
far2 <- function(x, h){forecast(Arima(x, order=c(2,0,0)), h=h)}
e <- tsCV(lynx, far2, h=1)
```

meaning that `forecast(Arima(x,order=c(2,0,0)),h=h)` would be applied successively to the time series lynx  using the rolling forecast origin. 
To make this only slightly more complicated, there is also the `window` argument which provides a rolling window instead of a rolling origin. My question is: when we apply `forecast(Arima(x,order=c(2,0,0)),h=h)` repeatedly are we repeatedly training a new ARIMA model on the new window of the time-series data? Or, is there some how and somewhere a persistent ARIMA model that is trained only once and then referenced for the further calls of the `forecast` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is repeatedly training a new ARIMA model on each subset of data.